# Events: Modify value on Form 1 -> set Global Variable and raise event -> update value on Form 2

Tags: events, view, model, controller

I'm spinning my wheels with what I think is a basic concept: receiving a 'data changed' notification from a GlobalData class.

I have Form1 with a single control on it (textBox1) which, when the number is changed, I set a corresponding property on 'global variable' class.

Now, when the property is set, I want to raise an event that Form2 can subscribe to and updates its indicator accordingly.

The basic structure is:
Form1 has textBox1 and button1, Form2 has textBox2, and GlobalClass has testValue.

Form1 stuff....

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public GlobalClass myGlobals= new GlobalClass();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            myGlobals.testValue= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        }
   }
```

GlobalClass stuff...

```
public class GlobalClass{
    private int mynum;       
    public int testValue{
        get{
            return mynum;}
        set{
            mynum = value;
          // NEED TO RAISE MY 'HEY YOUR testVALUE HAS CHANGED!!' EVENT HERE?
        }
   }
}
```

Form2 stuff

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form {
       public GlobalClass myGlobals2;

//NEED TO RECEIVE NOTIFICATION THAT myGlobals2.testValue HAS BEEN UPDATED? 
//THEN I CAN DO textBox2.Text = myGlobals2.testValue.ToString();

    }
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to read on .NET events and delegates.
2. You have to make the `GlobalClass` instance a true global variable:

`public class GlobalClass`

```
{
  public static GlobalClass Instance = new GlobalClass();

  public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

  private int mynum;       
  public int testValue{
    get{
      return mynum;}
    set{
      if (mynum != value)
      {
        mynum = value;
        // NEED TO RAISE MY 'HEY YOUR testVALUE HAS CHANGED!!' EVENT HERE?
        if (ValueChanged != null)
        {
          EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
          ValueChanged(this, e);
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

and address it like this:

```
GlobalClass.Instance.testValue = 3;
```

in `Form2`:

```
protected void OnValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   <your code>
}
```

In `Form2` constructor:

```
GlobalClass.Instance.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.OnValueChanged);
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. I've been doing a lot of web-based reading, but I'm not finding the specific answer to my example. Might have to go to the bookstore if I can't get some clear instruction here.
Even if I address the instance as you described (singleton?), I'm still lost with the raise and receipt of notifications for testValue.